# GWT Plugin Firefox 12

Tags: firefox, gwt

I want to use FireFox 12 for GWT development.
But this version is NOT officially supported by Google.

I found 
http://notepad2.blogspot.de/2012/04/gwt-developers-plugin-for-firefox-12.html

Is it save to use this plugins? Or I am in danger to catch malware?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stefan, I use mainly Firefox in my GWT projects and was able to switch to FF12 thanks to Alan Leung of Google who [posted Dev Mode plugin builds for FF12 on all major platforms](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!starred/google-web-toolkit/7OR5LM1POzI). It's safest to download the plugin from there. I've been using the Mac universal binary build for about a week now without a problem.

Comment: straightforward links from that thread: [linux32](http://acleung.com/ff12-linux32.xpi), [linux64](http://acleung.com/ff12-linux64.xpi), [mac universal lib](http://acleung.com/ff12-mac.xpi), [windows](http://acleung.com/ff12-win.xpi).

Answer (score 2):

The code to update the plugin is still [under review](http://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/1701803/) . Either rollback to Firefox 11 or use Chrome.